# How to set `ElevationRequired` for `TBitBtn`

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I need to mark a `TBitBtn` (not `TButton`), that the button action requires elevation. I set `ElevationRequired` to True, but I do not get the shield icon.

To reproduce, place a `TButton` and a `TBitBtn` on a form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Button1.ElevationRequired := True;
    BitBtn1.ElevationRequired := True;
end;
```

`Button1` is displayed with shield icon, `BitBtn1` is not.

Comment: Obvious question: Why TBitBtn? What are you missing in TButton?

Comment: The `ElevationRequired` property is not published for `TBitBtn`, so I guess the feature is not supported by that kind of button.

Comment: @UweRaabe I try to manipulate a form created with JVCLs `JvDSADialogs.CreateDSAMessageForm`. `CreateDSAMessageForm` internally uses `TBitBtn`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible.

A VCL [`TBitBtn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TBitBtn) is an [*owner-drawn*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) Win32 [BUTTON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) control. You can see that here:

```pascal
procedure TBitBtn.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do Style := Style or BS_OWNERDRAW;
end;
```

Hence, a `TBitBtn` is *not* drawn by Windows but manually by the Pascal code in `Vcl.Buttons.pas`. Specifically, `TBitBtn.DrawItem(const DrawItemStruct: TDrawItemStruct)` does the painting.

And here you can see that there is no mentioning of `ElevationRequired`.

Hence, `TBitBtn` doesn't support this.

In general, don't use `TBitBtn`; use `TButton` to get the native Win32 button.

Comment: I agree with Andreas. Don't expect this functionality to work on `TBitBtn`. `TBitBtn` is actually left in Delphi for backward compatibility with program written in legacy code. You see back in the days of first Delphi versions the standard `TButton` didn't support showing any icon. Only a simple caption. It is only later on that standard `TButton` would be extended by the ability to also show an icon. But `TBitBtn` was left in so you could still compile old legacy programs even on moder Delphi versions. Well with minimal refactoring.

Comment: Any way if you are forced to make use of `TBitBtn` why don't you design yourself custom icons that would already contain the Shield in them nad use them instead of the regular icons you may be using now. The shield icon is merely a visual aid for end user. Nothing more. So it doesn't matter whether the shield icon is shown by the system or manually by you.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Or use `LoadIcon(0, IDI_SHIELD)` or some of the other approaches like `LoadIconWithScaleDown` to get a high-quality shield in the right size.

Answer (score 1):

As `ElevationRequired` is not implemented for `TBitBtn` (see [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802268/2306907)). I ended up drawing the shield icon via this procedure (Vista+):

```
procedure MarkElevationRequired(ABitBtn: TBitBtn);
var
    Icon: TIcon;
begin
    Assert(Assigned(ABitBtn));
    //---
    try
        Icon := TIcon.Create;
        try
            Icon.Handle := GetSystemIcon(SIID_SHIELD, TSystemIconSize.Small); //see WinApi.ShellApi
            ABitBtn.Glyph.Assign(Icon);
        finally
            Icon.Free;
        end;
    except
        //CreateSystemIcon throws an exception for <WinVista
    end;
end;
```

with

```
/// Get system icon for SIID, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ne-shellapi-shstockiconid
/// Works for Win Vista or better
/// see https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/using-windows-stock-icons-in-delphi
function GetSystemIcon(Id: integer; Size: TSystemIconSize = TSystemIconSize.Large;
  Overlay: Boolean = False; Selected: Boolean = False): HICON;
var
    Flags: Cardinal;
    SSII: TSHStockIconInfo;
    ResCode: HResult;
begin
    if not TOSVersion.Check(6, 0) then
      raise Exception.Create('SHGetStockIconInfo is only available in Win Vista or better.');

    case Size of
        TSystemIconSize.Large: Flags := SHGSI_ICON or SHGSI_LARGEICON;
        TSystemIconSize.Small: Flags := SHGSI_ICON or SHGSI_SMALLICON;
        TSystemIconSize.ShellSize: Flags := SHGSI_ICON or SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE;
    end;

    if Selected then
      Flags := Flags OR SHGSI_SELECTED;
    if Overlay then
      Flags := Flags OR SHGSI_LINKOVERLAY;

    SSII.cbSize := SizeOf(SSII);
    ResCode := SHGetStockIconInfo(Id, Flags, SSII);

    if ResCode <> S_OK then
    begin
        if ResCode = E_INVALIDARG then
          raise Exception.Create(
            'The stock icon identifier [' + IntToStr(id) + '] is invalid')
        else
          raise Exception.Create(
            'Error calling GetSystemIcon: ' + IntToStr(ResCode));
    end
    else
      Result := SSII.hIcon;
end;
```